# Controlling the Activity Stack from an already started activity?

Tags: android, search, android-activity

I have a  productlist activity, which is called from a category list *as well* as from search.

When the user searches multiple times, then hits the back button, he has to step back all searches (=normal Android behaviour).

What I try to achieve is that searches are not put on the Acticity Stack, so hitting back will always bring him to the last activity before his 1-n searches.

Example activity flow:

1. dashboard
2. categories
3. productlist (from categories)
4. (search)
5. productlist (from search)
6. (maybe more searches)
7. productlist (from search)
   ...

I tried android:launchMode="singleTop" as described here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#LifeCycle

Works, but since I re-use the same productlist activity for category navigation and search, this happens:

- Without 'singleTop', the user has to step back all 'productlist (from search)' activities
- With 'singleTop' the user ends (of course) on activity 'categories', but should on 'productlist (from categories)'
- Since the SearchManager fires the intent, I cannot use intent flags.

Any chance to tell the already started activity (in case it is called by a search) to remove itself from the activity stack?

Thanks!